# Concurrency issue while accessing Dbcontext in EF Core

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-core, rabbitmq

I hooked up an Eventhandler to RabbitMQ message publisher and I am trying to insert those messages into a DB table as and when they are published. But when multiple messages are published simultaneously I am facing issue to access the database while querying. A System.NotSupportedException is thrown saying that a second operation has started before the previous asynchronous operation is completed.

```
public class RmqMessageHandler
{

    public void Register()
    {
        EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(RmqChannel);
        consumer.Received += EventingBasicConsumer.Received;
        RmqChannel.BasicConsume(queue: QueueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

    }

    private async void EventingBasicConsuner_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs message)
    {
        var body = message.Body;
        var encodedmessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.Span);
        var transaction = await DbRepo.Query<AccTransaction>().Where(X => X.Id == encodedmessage.Id).ToListAsync();
        if(transaction.count == 0)
        {
            DbRepo.StageNewItem(transaction);                
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using lock to lock the dbcontext in order to avoid concurrency issue like below.

```
lock(locker)
{
    var transaction = DbRepo.Query<AccTransaction>().Where(X => X.Id == encodedmessage.Id).ToList();
    if(transaction.count == 0)
    {
        DbRepo.StageNewItem(transaction);                
    }
}
```

but that is also throwing System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException saying The underlying provider failed on open or System.InvalidOperationException saying that the previous connection was not closed.

How can I overcome this issue..

Comment: Maybe it helps if you make `DbRepo` a local variable which you create newly at every call of `EventingBasicConsuner_Received`

Comment: Are you disposing the context somewhere? Check the amount of connections in your connection pool if your amount of connections is increasing indefinitely, maybe the connection are not being closed.

Comment: @Luty Yeah the previous connection is not being closed(since the read and/or write operation is not completed) before trying to establish a new one(since new message has arrived and it also needs to written to the DB)

Comment: @SomeBody I am not able to understand why the locking scenario is not working here

Comment: Your `DbRepo` needs to create a service scope for each operation and use a different `DbContext` instance

Comment: DbContext is not thread safe. Use a new context. You can use DbContextFactory.

Comment: @MateusZampol Even though I use new DbRepo object every time still getting an error that "second operation started before the previous one was completed"

Comment: @daniherrera could you please let me know why is the lock(Locker) not working (allowing another query operation on the table before the earlier operation is finished)

Comment: @ravikiranreddy may be `Locker` is a local object and `DbReport` is global. In any case, using a lock is not an elegant approach. The right approach is to use [DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) and create a new DbContext on each request. The DbContext live time should be short: _"A DbContext instance is designed to be used for a single unit-of-work. This means that the lifetime of a DbContext instance is usually very short."_

Comment: @daniherrera Is SemaphoreSlim(1) any better than lock.

Comment: @ravikiranreddy with SemaphoreSlim the advantage is that you can include async code inside, but, I say again, this is not the way to test DbContext.